# Add an attribute to a Numpy array in runtime

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to add an attribute to a Numpy ndarray using setattr, but I get an error:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 4])
setattr(x, 'new_attr', 1)
```

> AttributeError: numpy.ndarray object has no attribute new_attr

How can I add a new attribute to a Numpy ndarray?

Comment: You can't, it's implemented in C. Try to subclass it

Comment: Why do you want to add a new attribute to it?

Comment: You cannot, the type doesn't allow it.

Comment: @LucasNg I require lots of matrix inverses and Matrix_name.I is a particularly handy way , unfortunately the numpy.matrix may be removed from future versions[1] so creating a subclass from np.ndarray with a I (inverse) property is the only option .

[1] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 4):

Using your example and refering to [Simple example - adding an extra attribute to ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#simple-example-adding-an-extra-attribute-to-ndarray), something you can do is

```
class YourArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, your_new_attr=None):        
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.your_new_attr = your_new_attr
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.your_new_attr = getattr(obj, 'your_new_attr', None)
```

and then

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 4])
>>> x_ = YourArray(x)
>>> x_.your_new_attr = 2
>>> x_.your_new_attr
2
```

or directly at instantiation

```
>>> # x_ = YourArray([1, 2, 4], your_new_attr=3) works as well
>>> x_ = YourArray(x, your_new_attr=3)
>>> x_.your_new_attr
3
```

Answer (score 2):

May the [metadata](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.metadata.html) type of numpy helps? It allows to set up a new dtype (based on an existing one) where you can attach key value pairs.

For your array, that would be

```py
dt = np.dtype(int, metadata={"new_attr": 1})
x = np.array([1, 2, 4], dtype=dt)
print(x.dtype.metadata)
```

Comment: Doesn't this add the attribute to the type (`np.array`) and not to an instance (`x`) ?

Comment: @DeepSpace: You are right: Technically, the metadata is attached to the dtype (which, in turn, is attached to the array). I agree, it may be unwiedly to create own dtypes just to attach metadata.

Comment: @DeepSpace: No. It attaches the data to the dtype, which is a different thing from the type.