# How can we give a Numpy array custom slice attributes?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Numpy arrays to represent different multi-dimensional physical quantities. For example, I might have a (6,) array (let's call it `linear`) where the first 3 elements represent 3D position of an object, and the last 3 elements represent 3D velocity of that object. I might also have defined a (7,) array (let's call it `angular`) where the first 4 elements represent a quaternion describing an objects rotation and the last 3 elements represent the angular velocity.

To access parts of these arrays I might do things like:

```
position = linear[:3]
angular_velocity = angular[-3:]
```

When it gets overwhelming to remember the slices (which it does when the arrays incorporate more information) I can do:

```
class Linear:
    p_slice = slice(0, 3)
    v_slice = slice(3, 6)

class Angular:
    q_slice = slice(0, 4)
    omega_slice = slice(4, 7)

position = linear[Linear.p_slice]
angular_velocity = angular[Angular.omega_slice]
```

This is a bit neater, but I still have to make sure I always know which type of variable I'm working with otherwise I might use the wrong type of slice like `linear[Angular.q_slice]` (whoops, I thought `linear` was an instance of my angular orientation/velocity arrays). So I'd rather make sure I'm disallowed from using the wrong type of slice with something like:

```
class Linear(np.ndarray):
    def p(self):
        return self[:3]

# make an instance of Linear

position = linear.p
```

I'm considering subclassing `ndarray` as I suggested above, but I'm wondering if there are better ways (and I'd like to avoid having to deal with the gotchas of subclassing `ndarray`). I definitely want to treat my objects as `ndarray`s though, so that means I don't want to wrap them in some other object type and have to access the `ndarray` as an instance property.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67509913/add-an-attribute-to-a-numpy-array-in-runtime?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it kind of helps. The first answer suggests subclassing which I'm aware of but I'd like to know if there's a better way to get the job done. The second answer is not relevant.

Comment: numpy lets you create custom dtypes for this sort of thing. Have you considered this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: @SimonTartakovksy would that not mean I'd need to put a 3-tuple in one array position for the 3D position for instance? That would mean I'm not really able to use my array as a regular `ndarray` for mathematical operations like dot product or matrix multiplication.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Yep, would not be able to do that kind of thing. That being said what unified mathematical operation makes sense on an array containing both position and velocity? There really is not much performance benefit to merging the sets of floats into one array. Why not make two separate arrays, perhaps an object which contains them so you can define some useful operations on them?

Comment: @SimonTartakovksy I'm working with Kalman filters so the "state space" includes things like position, velocity, orientation, angular velocity etc. The algorithm is agnostic to the physical meaning of all of the state space dimensions so mixing them in any way is fine as long as I'm consistent with the ordering. So there are just matrix operations on this abstract state space. But whenever I want insight into what the state space represents in terms of my physical quantities I need to use slicing.